# css display flex and new line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using display:flex to make some awesome page.
Inside this div I couldn't make newline. 
Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vp4rzk8v/
Simply I need to make "Kartlar" on new line. Here is my code:

```
<style>
body {
  background: rgba(13, 190, 81, .5);
}
.customcol:hover {
  background: rgba(13, 190, 81, .8);
}

.customcol {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  height: 86vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.fa-6x {
  font-size: 6em;
}

.fa-7x {
  font-size: 7em;
}
</style>
     <div class="col customcol">
      <i class="fa fa-credit-card fa-5x " aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <div>
        <h3>Kartlar</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also add `flex-direction: column` to the **.customcol** class.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `flex-wrap: wrap;` and `align-content: center;` to your `.customcol` rule and set the with of the div with **Kartlar** to `100%`. Here is updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vp4rzk8v/1/

Comment: it worked, but now the word "Kartlar" and the card icon is too far away :/ I just wanted new line not new page :)

Comment: Ok there is it, add also `align-content: center;` to your `.customcol` rule, Here is an update https://jsfiddle.net/vp4rzk8v/2/